# How to search & replace within a cell value?

Tags: microsoft-excel, find-and-replace

I have a cell A and its value is `122abb12`.

In another cell B, I want its value to be the value in cell B but  all `1` should be replaced by `I` - value in cell B should be `I22abbI2`.

What is the function to use in this case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe you are looking for the Substitute function:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A1,1,"I")
```

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for, is the "replace" function. If cell A contains 122abb12, and you want the 1's to be replaced to I in cell B but keep the rest: the replace function could look somewhat like this: =REPLACE(A1;"1";"I")

Comment: Sorry for my confusion. I have update my question.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry I misunderstood the question.

Comment: Better this time around?

Comment: I'm using excel 2010 and don't have the method's argument list as you mention.

Comment: This would work like any other function within Excel. I testet this on a Norwegian version, so it's called something else for me (the translated version of replace). A quick google search, tells me that the function exists and is documented as "REPLACE" in the English version. You could perhaps find it if you press the "fX" button (functions button) next to the input-bar? You will then get a list with the ability to search through!